# Cannot assign to 'initialState' because it is a read-only property

Tags: typescript

Can't assign to  a read-only property in constructor when it run in method,

the typescript version is 3.4.1

```
class Example {
   readonly initialState: any
   constructor(){
      this.someMethod()
   }
   private someMethod(){
     this.initialState = 'someState'
   }

}
```

Comment: You can only assign read only fields in the constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`readonly` properties can only be [initialized in place during declaration, or inside the constructor](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#readonly-modifier). The rationale here is that that method could potentially be called from somewhere else in your code, and attempt to set the property value again, so TypeScript blocks it entirely.

PS. I believe the code was just not copy-and-pasted correctly, since there's no `setState()` method in your class; your code would not run. I'm assuming you meant to say something like `this.initialState = 'someState'`. If you want to revise your question, there might be a different answer.

Comment: Is there any way to run it in the method ?  I'm using `(this.initialState as any) = 'someState' `, but I wonder is there any better way to handle it?

Comment: No. That defeats the purpose of using `readonly`. You might as well allow writing, but set it as `private` instead.